# What's the best way to generate Excel 2007+ files from XSLT?

Tags: excel, xslt

Coming from many different languages, I got stuck in ERP development. The thing is that our ERP is using XSL transformations to generate Excel files in SpreadsheetML format, which is saved with `.xls` extension, so that Windows open it within Excel.

This results in many unnecessary clicks that our users are forced into; excel screaming about "repairing" the file, wanting to save it with `.xml` extension - so our users have to pick *correct* extension in order to send it to client / colleagues... That's just unnecessary load from user standpoint.

Now, due to historical reasons we are unable to ditch the XSLT (and hey! it's awesome anyway) but what we **do** want to is to make the entire process streamlined from *the user standpoint*.

### Generating 2007+ formats

In the end - after researching google *thoroughly*, I ended up writing xslt transformations "*engine*" which allows us to generate valid 2007 formats. All we do now is to generate the contents of `sheet.xml` in [OpenXML format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278309.aspx). It also allows us to generate macro-enabled excel files.

But seriously, is there something I missed? Is there **any** other way how to generate the Excel OpenXML format with some already maintained solution?

The SpreadsheetML is one way how to do it, I don't like it because it introduces a huge demand on end-user and does not contain images/macros. Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

### SpreadsheetML confusion

When I say *SpreadsheetML* I mean [the "XML Spreadsheet"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066%28office.10%29.aspx) . I've noticed that Microsoft is calling the OpenXML Excel format **also** as SpreadsheetML - which makes me confused.

Comment: [Here's the way how we do it now](https://github.com/foglcz/xsl-excel-engine). I'm, actually looking for a solution, that is already maintained / already has it's community.

Comment: this engine doesn't support outlining, as I see?